# Unable to execute .exe file with parameters in java

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, runtime

I am trying to execute an .exe file(Say abc.exe) which I would execute from command line as:

```
C:\....pathtoExe>abc.exe /m param1
```

The code is:

```
                String cmd[]={"bin/ocr/abc.exe","/m",param1};
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                p.waitFor();
```

Pls note that the bin/ocr/abc.exe is the relative path of the exe file and is correct one. Hoewver when I get the input stream and try to read it, I dont get the desired output(Infact I dont get any output at all as inputStream returns nothing).
I also have a batch file in the same directory(run.bat) with the following code:

```
abc.exe /m %1 > abc_out.txt
```

This can be executed from command prompt as:

```
C:\...pathtobat>run.bat param1
```

So how do I execute above batch file which takes a parameter from command prompt? My main aim is to run the .exe file properly from java and get the output returned from the .exe file.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
String cmd[]= { "abc.exe", "/c", param1 };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
p.waitFor();
```